# ReactiveCommand Subscribe not found

Tags: reactiveui

The world is changing so fast I updated ReactiveUI version on my project and my code does not compile anymore. In this particular case I cannot see .Subscribe() on ReactiveCommand anymore. The closest I found was .SubscribeToExpressionChain() which I have no idea what it is. [The documentation](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/commands/reactive-commands.html) or even the code sample on [their main Repo's Readme.MD](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI#update-the-user-interface) continues to say and/or assume ReactiveCommand is an IObservable. Where do I access latest documentation? Am I missing any obvious clue here?

> Reactive commands are themselves observable. Whenever any execution of the command completes, the result will tick through the command itself.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the basic `ReactiveCommand` type is just an abstract type and does not support IObservable. My member types were ReactiveCommand instead of `ReactiveCommand<TParam, TResult>` which they should have been.